# Build PyTorch from Source for Specific Python Version

Tags: python, git, pytorch

I have been following [this source](https://datagraphi.com/blog/post/2021/9/13/building-pytorch-from-source-on-windows-to-work-with-an-old-gpu) to build PyTorch from source for my older graphics card (GeForce RTX960M, compute capability of 5.0).

I ran it initially without specifying a Torch version I needed and it built from source without any issues. What I didn't know was that PyTorch would be built using Python version 3.12 (I think my mistake was that my conda environment was using 3.12), so it was incompatible with the program I was trying to run (which requires Python 3.10).

Before I spend hours building PyTorch from source again, do I need to do anything in addition to the below for Step 10 from the link? I already setup a new conda environment that uses Python 3.10.13.
I need to build PyTorch version 2.0.1 for Cuda 11.8 and running on Python 3.10.13.

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch
```

```
git checkout v2.0.1
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --jobs 0
```